# System Verilog Counterpart for 'sync' of Specman e

Tags: synchronization, wait, system-verilog, specman

I would like to ask what is the counterpart of `sync` of Specman e in the System Verilog Language.

I understand that `@ event_indentifier` is equivalent to `wait @ event` of Specman e.
But how about `sync @ event` ?

Answer (score 1):

For named events, you can use the `triggered` property.

```
event ev;
...
wait (ev.triggered);
```

See chapter 15.5.3 of the the 2012 SystemVerilog LRM for a full explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Part of 13.1.1 of IEEE 1647 says

> The sync action is similar to the wait action, except that a wait action **always** requires at least one cycle of the TCM’s sampling event before execution can continue. With a sync action, execution can continue in the same time step.

Part of draft of 1647-2008

For `sync`

> When an TCM reaches a sync action, its execution shall be suspended so some other TCM, or the suspended TCM itself, can be scheduled for execution.

For `wait`

> When a TCM reaches a wait action, its execution shall be suspended so some other TCM can be scheduled for execution. The suspended TCM itself shall remain idle and shall not be scheduled until the next
>   occurrence of the sampling event.

I think you are comparing the different things. *SystemVerilog* is the simulation engine and kernel, and *Specman* is like a add-on or plugin on to the kernel to monitor and check something you wrote in *e* language. In *SystemVerilog* the event is for its simulation events, and *Specman* also creates it own events for its TCM processes. So in *Specman*, it has its own TCM process scheduling. If you use `sync`, it could make the synchronization without extra cycle; use `wait` and cause at least one cycle for the sampling cycle. Of course, if `sync` and `wait` does not have the temporal expression, they both use the TCM default sampling events and could have one or more cycles.

*SystemVerilog* is also event-based simulator. It does have delta cycles in each time step.
You can download IEEE 1800-2012 SystemVerilog LRM in http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf, and see 4.5 for its scheduling reference  algorithm.
But in the Hardware modeling, it has no explicitly `wait` synx for zero cycle delay in the current simulation time step because the simulator will automatically schedule the process with sensitivity list to be run. If you have to compare *Specman* with *SystemVerilog*, it should be specifically *SystemVerilog Assertion* syntax. There is `##0` syntax in SVA to cause the assertion process to have zero cycle delay before next assertion expressions.